# Create shared library from c-source code for Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, c, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to build a simple sip-application using Xamarin Forms. I use [PjSip](http://www.pjsip.org/) as a tool to sip functionality. I have a source-file (.c) with some methods which I want to call from my Xamarin application.
I have already built a static library (.a) for Xamarin ios and created a wrapper using p/invoke to call methods from my c-file. And it works perfect. But now I'm stuck on building shared libs (.so) to use them in Xamarin android.
I'm looking for step-by-step guide building shared libraries for Xamarin android starting with c-source code and ending with linking libs to a real Xamarin Android application. But still I would very appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

[Build and Debug C++ Libraries in Xamarin.Android Apps with Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.xamarin.com/build-and-debug-c-libraries-in-xamarin-android-apps-with-visual-studio-2015/)

**Overview**

- Install Visual Studio 2015
- Create a new Visual C++ Dynamic Shared Library project
- Reference this project in you Xamarin project
- Use `DllImport` to access the C code. Example:

  ```
  [DllImport ("sanangeles", 
               EntryPoint = "Java_com_example_SanAngeles_DemoGLSurfaceView_nativePause")]
  static extern void nativePause (IntPtr jnienv);
  ```
- Browse [this project](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SanAngeles_NDK/SanAngeles_NativeDebug/SanAngeles) to get a deeper view

When you do it like this you can even debug the C Code while running the Xamarin.Android app in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: It would be great if I could do it in this way. But I don't understand some things. First of all when I add reference from my Xamarin Android project to a new Dynamic Shared Library project I get a warning `The project 'DynamicSipProject' cannot be referenced. An assembly must have a 'dll' or 'exe' extension in order to be referenced`.    The second is after compiling pjsip source-code I have a lot of static libs (.a). How can I use them in this dynamic shared library project?